# How to import lib WindowsAzure ionic 3

Tags: azure, ionic3

I need import WindowsAzure to use in my project ionic.

`import { WindowsAzure } from 'cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps';`

Not working import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import * as WindowsAzure from 'azure-mobile-apps-client';
```